# MongoDB replica set write when secondary down

Tags: mongodb, database-replication

I am trying to create a master-slave mongo instances. I created to instances:

```
mongod.exe --config "C:\mongodb\config\repl1.cfg"
mongod.exe --config "C:\mongodb\config\repl2.cfg"
```

Then I logged into my first node and created replicas, second node is started as well:

```
mongo.exe --port 27031
mongo.exe --port 27032


rs.initiate( {
   _id : "replKK",
   members: [
      { _id: 0, host: "localhost:27031", priority:5 },
      { _id: 1, host: "localhost:27032", hidden: true, priority:0 }
   ]
})
```

I can read and write when both nodes are up. But when I shut down the secondary node I can insert into collection, because I'm getting following error:

```
WriteCommandError({
        "topologyVersion" : {
                "processId" : ObjectId("6149c7170fc6426b073f16c3"),
                "counter" : NumberLong(11)
        },
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "not master",
        "code" : 10107,
        "codeName" : "NotWritablePrimary",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1632225689, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1632225689, 1)
})
```

What I am doing wrong? How can I achieve that first node is the instance that can insert rows and secondary is just kind of backup (master-slave)? I'm using MongoDB 5.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to elect a writable PRIMARY node, the **majority** of all nodes must be up.

1 out of 2 is not the majority. Typical solution is to create an [Arbiter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-arbiter/). An Arbiter is a very lightweight mongod process, it does not store any data.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my issue. Can you please tell me if it's possible to run primary + arbitrary without the secondary? When I try to read data I' m getting
        "errmsg" : "not master and slaveOk=false",
        "codeName" : "NotPrimaryNoSecondaryOk",

Comment: You could run primary + arbitrary but it does not gain anything. When the arbiter goes down then you still have the primary, i.e. no changes. When it primary goes down, then the application is not available anymore, because the arbiter does not store **any** data.

Comment: hmm I tried this approach but I wasn't able to find any data because of NotPrimaryNoSecondaryOk

Comment: Well, I never tested this setup - because it does not make any sense.